Python Web Scraping Selenium, no muestra el contenido de un div mediante xpath
estoy intentando extraer datos del sitio web: https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all
mediante web scraping con python, estoy utilizando la librería Selenium, adjunto el código:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

URL = 'https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all'

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

driver.get(URL)

max_items = int(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'all-product-count').text.split()[0])
print("=" * 80, f"{max_items} items disponibles", "=" * 80, sep="\n")

scroll_attempts = 0
max_scroll_attempts = 50
previous_length = 0

# Obtener el título de cada item, simulando el scroll para que lea todos los artículos
while len(titles := driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="product-item-title"]')) < max_items and scroll_attempts < max_scroll_attempts:
    current_length = len(titles)
    print(f"Obtenidos {current_length} de {max_items}, {(current_length / max_items * 100):.2f}%")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Aumentado el tiempo de espera para asegurar la carga completa de los elementos
    scroll_attempts += 1
    if current_length == previous_length:
        break
    previous_length = current_length

# Reset scroll attempts for next set of elements
scroll_attempts = 0
previous_length = 0

# Obtener los precios de cada item
while len(prices := driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="price money"]')) < max_items and scroll_attempts < max_scroll_attempts:
    current_length = len(prices)
    print(f"Obtenidos {current_length} de {max_items}, {(current_length / max_items * 100):.2f}%")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Aumentado el tiempo de espera para asegurar la carga completa de los elementos
    scroll_attempts += 1
    if current_length == previous_length:
        break
    previous_length = current_length

# Reset scroll attempts for next set of elements
scroll_attempts = 0
previous_length = 0

print(f"Obtenidos {max_items} de {max_items}, 100.00%")

# Obtener las descripciones de cada item
desc_xpath = '//div[class="ec-description-container tabs-are-shown"]'
descriptions = []
while len(descriptions := driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, desc_xpath)) < max_items and scroll_attempts < max_scroll_attempts:
    current_length = len(descriptions)
    print(f"Obtenidos {current_length} de {max_items}, {(current_length / max_items * 100):.2f}%")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)
    scroll_attempts += 1
    if current_length == previous_length:
        break
    previous_length = current_length

# Imprimir cada uno de los títulos con su respectivo precio y descripción
print("=" * 80, "ITEMS", "=" * 80, sep="\n")
for i in range(max_items):
    title = titles[i].text

    # Encontrar los precios para cada item
    item_xpath = f'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[{i+1}]//span[@class="price money"]'
    item_prices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, item_xpath)

    # Debugging output
    print(f"Item {i+1}: encontrado {len(item_prices)} precios")

    # Como algunos artículos tienen 2 precios, seleccionamos el segundo precio si hay dos, de lo contrario seleccionamos el primero
    if len(item_prices) >= 2:
        price = item_prices[1].text
    elif len(item_prices) == 1:
        price = item_prices[0].text
    else:
        price = "precio no disponible"

    # Obtener todo el contenido del contenedor de descripción

    desc_xpath = f'//div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][{i+1}]//p'
    print(f"Buscando descripción con XPath: {desc_xpath}")
    try:
        desc_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, desc_xpath)
        desc = " ".join([elem.text for elem in desc_elements]) if desc_elements else "descripcion no disponible"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al obtener la descripción para el item {i+1}: {str(e)}")
        desc = "descripcion no disponible"

    print(f"{title} - {price} - {desc}")

driver.quit()

Pude extraer la información de los títulos y los precios, pero estoy teniendo dificultades con las descripciones, como se puede ver en el código, muestra los títulos y descripciones utilizando el xpath de sus contenedores, pero al momento de hacer lo mismo con las descripciones no funciona:
#Obtener las descripciones de cada item
desc_xpath = f'//div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][{i+1}]//p'
print(f"Buscando descripción con XPath: {desc_xpath}")
try:
    desc_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, desc_xpath)
    desc = " ".join([elem.text for elem in desc_elements]) if desc_elements else "descripcion no disponible"
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error al obtener la descripción para el item {i+1}: {str(e)}")
    desc = "descripcion no disponible"

Ya intenté poner de diferentes maneras el xpath del contenedor div que contiene los párrafos de la descripción pero no muestra ninguno:
item_desc_xpath = f'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div[{i+1}]//p'
desc_xpath = f'//li[{i+1}]//div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")]'

la salida sigue siendo la misma:
Obtenidos 496 de 517, 95.94%
Obtenidos 512 de 517, 99.03%
Obtenidos 517 de 517, 100.00%
Obtenidos 0 de 517, 0.00%
================================================================================
ITEMS
================================================================================
Item 1: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][1]//p
Best Fitness Ab Board BFAB10 - �199.00 - descripcion no disponible
Item 2: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][2]//p
Best Fitness Ab Board Hyperextension BFHYP10 - �245.00 - descripcion no disponible
Item 3: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][3]//p
Best Fitness Adjustable Bench BFFID25 - �199.00 - descripcion no disponible
Item 4: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][4]//p
Best Fitness Bench BFFID10 - �245.00 - descripcion no disponible
Item 5: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][5]//p
Best Fitness Cable Crossover BFCCO10 - �599.00 - descripcion no disponible
Item 6: encontrado 1 precios
Buscando descripci�n con XPath: //div[contains(@class, "ec-description-container tabs-are-shown")][6]//p
Best Fitness Center Drive Elliptical BFE1 - �1,995.00 - descripcion no disponible

Como se puede observar, muestra el título y el precio, pero no las descripciones, no sé si estoy poniendo mal el xpath del contenedor que tiene las descripciones en cada item, (las clases de ese contenedor son: (class="ec-description-container tabs-are-shown" y su xpath obtenido con el inspector de google chrome es:
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div), si alguien pudiera ayudarme a encontrar la manera de extraer las descripciones lo agradecería demasiado

Si no me estoy confundiendo, la descripción del producto no aparece en la lista de productos inicial que obtienes (como ocurre con el precio y el título), sino que hay que hacer click en el link de cada producto para acceder a su página propia donde si aparece la descripción, especificaciones, etc
Por otro lado, te estás complicando demasiado para obtener el título y precio, en vez de generar el XPATH dinámicamente para cada uno, puedes hacer una buscada de cada iten de la lista ("product-item-info") y luego simplemente buscar por cada uno las clases "price" y "product-item-title". Este último item contiene también el href para acceder a la página propia de cada producto, en la cual obtienes la descripción.
Por ejemplo:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


URL = 'https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all'

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
opts.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

driver.get(URL)

max_items = int(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'all-product-count').text.split()[0])
print("=" * 80, f"{max_items} items disponibles", "=" * 80, sep="\n")

scroll_attempts = 0
max_scroll_attempts = 50
previous_length = 0

# Obtener el título de cada item, simulando el scroll para que lea todos los artículos
while len(items := driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//section[@class="product-item-info"]')) < max_items and scroll_attempts < max_scroll_attempts:
    current_length = len(items)
    print(f"Obtenidos {current_length} de {max_items}, {(current_length / max_items * 100):.2f}%")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)  # Aumentado el tiempo de espera para asegurar la carga completa de los elementos
    scroll_attempts += 1
    if current_length == previous_length:
        break
    previous_length = current_length
print(f"Obtenidos {current_length} de {max_items}, {(current_length / max_items * 100):.2f}%")

# Iteramos sobre cada items para obtener la información relevante
products = []
for item in items:
    # Obtener del título del producto
    title_item = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-item-title")
    product_title = title_item.text
    
    # Obtener el precio del producto
    price_items = item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "price")
    product_price = price_items[-1].text if price_items else "No disponible"
    
    # Obtener link al producto
    product_link = title_item.get_attribute('href')
    
    products.append({
        "title": product_title,
        "price": product_price,
        "link": product_link
    })
    

# Visitar cada el enlace de cada producto y obtener descripción
for i, product in enumerate(products, start=1):
    
    driver.get(product["link"])
    description_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "ec-description-container")
        )
    )
    product_description = "".join(p.text for p in description_item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p"))
    product["description"] = product_description
    
    
    # Imprimir los datos
    print("-" * 80, f"Producto {i} de {max_items}", "-" * 80, sep="\n")
    print(f"Título: {product['title']}")
    print(f"Precio: {product['price']}")
    print(f"Descripción:\n {product['description']}")
    
driver.quit()

Se usa una lista de diccionarios para almacenar la información relevante de la primera página (el listado de productos), como es el título, el precio y el enlace a la pagina propia de cada producto. A continución solo nos queda iterar sobre cada producto, visitar su página y obtener la descripción.
Ten en cuenta que esta forma de proceder (ir visitando uno a uno, en orden y de forma continuada las paginas de todos los productos) es muy sospechosa de no ser obra de un humano... Si el servidor tiene implementado algún mecanismo anti-scraping pudiera que te mandara a paseo... Si se diera el caso hay formas de intentar no enfadarlo, como usar tiempos de espera aleatorios, aleatorizar el acceso a los links, cambios de IP, etc

Muchas gracias bro!, buenas observaciones, la verdad estoy aprendiendo y cada concepto nuevo es bueno, si tengo en cuenta que los sitios web pueden tener protecciones anti-scraping, por el momento si funciona, le añadí una excepción "TimeoutException" porque algunos artículos no tienen descripción, en esos casos muestra un mensaje de que no se pudo obtener la descripción:
except TimeoutException:
print(f"TimeoutException: No se pudo obtener la descripción para el producto {i}: {product['title']}")
product_description = "descripcion no disponible"
